# Loading a video in a byte array form from spring is not playing on mobile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mobile

I have a web service that loads a media file in a form of a byte array. It loads and plays perfectly on desktop web browser but fails on any mobile device.

Any tips on how to fix this?

I already set the necessary headers and still it doesn't play.

Update:

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output");
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=29030400, immutable");
        headers.add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        headers.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        headers.add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");

        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
                IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), 
                headers,
                HttpStatus.OK);
```

It load pretty well on desktop apps but not on mobile.

TIA.

Comment: Can you please show some configurations. MessageConverter beans, etc. Are you using some compressions? Please elaborate the question

Comment: Updated he question. I don't have any configurations, its just a normal pass through of the file to a Spring beans with Http Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this (thanks to a colleague of mine) is that Apple devices such as iphone/ipad treats all videos as a stream content. This means that when a device request for a mp4 (for example), it tries to get a partial content of the request in bytes.

This means that if the request is coming from an Apple device, the code should set the user agent and range appropriately.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","<User agent depending on the device");
conn.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes: 0-1023");
```